# Running Unit Tests Through Pipelines That Require Port Binding

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, .net-core, integration-testing

I've got an Azure pipeline that is building a .NET Core 3.0 project. It is running on a ubuntu-18.04 agent. It first publishes the repository with a `dotnet publish` component. It then tries to run a `dotnet test` component to run the integration tests within the project. If those tests pass, it then pushes the build out to deployment.

However, this application is a web server that wants to bind to a port (443 for SSL). So, unsurprisingly, when I try to run my unit tests on the agent I get:

> The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed :
>   Unhandled exception.  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (13):
>   Permission denied at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError
>   error, String callerName) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint
>   endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start() at
>   SimpleHttpServer.HttpServer.Listen() in  at
>   SimpleHttpServer.REST.RESTServer.<>c.<b__9_0>d.MoveNext()

...when the tests try to bind the `TcpListener` to the required port.

How can I solve this? Can I allow the pipeline agent to bind to this socket somehow?

To clarify - this is about the agent that is building and deploying the project, **not** the Azure service that runs the deployed version.

Comment: An important terminology note: Those aren't unit tests. They're integration tests. Unit tests run in isolation and don't require external dependencies like running web servers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for the correction.